# Identifying WHICH textbox is being executed

Tags: vba

I have a worksheet that has dozens of text boxes.  A number of them execute the same macro while a number of others execute another macro, etc.  I have five groups of text boxes executing five different macros.  Rather than writing a separate macro for each text box I grouped them together.  Now I want to be able to determine WHICH text box is executing the macro so I can perform filtering to limit the results.

I know the text box names for each text box by simply right clicking on the text box. I just don't know how to figure out the current text box being executed at this time.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set all checkboxes (form controls) to invoke the same macro. In the macro you can check which particular checkbox was clicked and its various properties as follows:

```
Dim chk As CheckBox
Dim str As String

Sub MyMacro()
    Set chk = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)
    str = "CheckBox with Index=" & chk.Index & " and Name='" & chk.Name & "' and Value="
    If chk.Value = Checked Then
        str = str & "True was clicked!"
    Else
        str = str & "False was clicked!"
    End If
    MsgBox str
End Sub
```

[image: 1]